# Singular fit with high degrees of freedom in LMM

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am running a linear mixed model on hierarchical data. I have 500 samples from 3 regions. Within each region, samples were taken from 3 urban and 3 nonurban sites. I am interested in how the classification of the site as urban or nonurban impacts trait y.

This is my model:
y ~ class + (1|region) + (1|site) + (1|sex)

I am running my model using lme4 in R with the following code:
lmer(y ~ class + (1|city) + (1|site) + (1|sex),
data=meas,
REML=TRUE)

And am given the message: boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

I believe that my singular fit is because the variance of the random effect of site is estimated at 0. When I remove this random effect, I no longer receive a message about the singular fit; **however, the denominator degrees of freedom obtained from running an anova on the model are extremely high (463.92). Is this an error in my model?**

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Your random effects don't seem sensible. I don't believe sex should ever be modelled a random effect and if you include both region and site as random effects, they should be nested. However, three "subjects" is usually considered not sufficient to estimate a random effect (after all, what you estimate there is ultimately the variance of a population).